# signature recognition algorithm for android

Tags: android

I am trying to build an android application that allows user to login through signing on a canvas, I can't find any algorithm that will help me implement this functionality in reliable manner , I read alot of papers and methods about signature recognition such as fourier transform method but all the papers involve very complex mathematical operations which makes it very hard to implement using the android sdk.

so is there any open source algorithm that would compare two signature bitmaps(drawables) to obtain descent results?
if not how should I go about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about it but I feel there is sample app installed in the emulator called `GestureBuilder` which can help you. You can refer [Gesture](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/10/gestures-on-android-16.html) for this.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing drawables may be not sufficient, as signatures  may differ in size and position. You can attempt recognition based on invariant moments ( I use this technology for OCR, 
but on printed characters, see demos in http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaocr/ project )

You may get better results analysing signature process in dynamics - path, speed,   energy etc.